# check if WordPress website has updates remotely

Tags: updates

I am setting up a HTML website that will allow me to manage all my websites from one place. I have already setup an up-time monitor, backup logger, and a to-do list. I am know looking at adding some code that will allow me to see if my WordPress websites have updates available. This way I don't need to login to all the websites to see if there are updates available. I would only need to login to the websites that need updating.

I don't want to use commercial stuff like ManageWP if I don't have to. Because, if I did use something like that, I would have to go to their website to access it. Also it would probably cost since I have many websites.

Is this possible at all? If so, some guidance would be appreciated.

One thought I had was that if I could log the updates to a database, then I could just display the database in the website to show updates.

Comment: you can use wp.com and jetpack connect if you're worried about cost, all free and you can run calypso locally so no visiting the site

Comment: I think I am just going to go with Jetpack as you suggested @TomJNowell.

Answer (score 2):

There is no dedicated way to check a version of WP install remotely. On other hand this isn't really complicated, you could scrape a page for `generator` meta tag or just `readme.html` of WP core since you would know exact location of it.

For checking what's available you can call to WordPress org updates API, you don't need WP for that. You can just implement that specific call, I have built more general library for myself while back — [WPorg Client](https://github.com/Rarst/wporg-client).

Honestly I would question reinventing these wheels however. Making this from scratch, running, and maintaining is a cost too.